# How can I transfer data from kindle to computer without a cable?

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite

I use kindle without using a USB cable most times. But when I want to export the `myclippings.txt` file, I have to use a cable to connect to computer.

I know there is a quick way to export notes, which is the export button under the notes tab. However personal documents cannot use the feature.

I have wanted this feature for several years, but still haven't found a way. So any great idea?